Hot restart error in Appears at start run app in android studio
I'm Working On IDE Android Studio in Flutter
When I write a new code and want to apply the new code, click on... Ctrl + S
It will not run and this message appears in the RUN menu. It will not run unless you lock the emulator and run it again.
...
this an code.....
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86...
Hot reload was rejected:
Error while starting Kernel isolate task.
Try performing a hot restart instead.
We will do a lot and it will be useless
